When running via command line, receive error ''no attribute predict_proba"
I have a set of code that, when I run it in a Python interpreter (3.8.4), everything works fine. However, when I try to run via the command line, I end up receiving an error:
AttributeError: This 'SelfTrainingClassifier' has no attribute 'predict_proba'

This is strange as when I go through the documentation, selfTrianingClassifier does have predcit_proba.
st_pipeline = Pipeline(
    [
        ("vect", CountVectorizer(**vectorizer_params)),
        ("tfidf", TfidfTransformer()),
        ("clf", SelfTrainingClassifier(SGDClassifier(**sdg_params), verbose=True)),
    ]
)


data = pd.read_excel("C:/data/sampledata.xlsx")
X_train_kd, X_test_kd, y_train_kd, y_test_kd = train_test_split(data ["tags"], data [label],train_size=0.3)
st_pipeline .fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred = st_pipeline.predict_proba(X_test)

Tried changing the script, looking online at the error. I don't understand why it is crashing.

It's hard to tell from your code, but predict_proba is only going to be a method of SelfTrainingClassifier if the underlying estimator has the predict_proba method too. Based on the SGDClassifier docos, your underlying estimator only has the method for certain values of the loss function, which depends on the value of sdg_params, which could be different in interactive mode?
